# Create the matrix with a repeating pattern (R)

Tags: r, math, matrix

There should be a matrix created without a vector. Like a simplified one without entering all the data in the vector.

```r
matrix(c(0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2), nrow = 5, ncol = 5)
```

I've tried:

```r
matrix(0:2, ncol=5, nrow=5)
```

```
 > matrix

      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
 [1,]    0    2    1    0    2
 [2,]    1    0    2    1    0
 [3,]    2    1    0    2    1
 [4,]    0    2    1    0    2
 [5,]    1    0    2    1    0
```

But it's not helping, as each column should start with the number the previous column ends with.

The final matrix should look like:

```
> matrix
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
 [1,]    0    1    2    0    1
 [2,]    1    2    0    1    2
 [3,]    2    0    1    2    0
 [4,]    0    1    2    0    1
 [5,]    1    2    0    1    2
```

Comment: Said differently ... describe what you think you need in your own words, show what you've tried, and why what you've done does not meet those requirements.

Comment: The sequence of `0:2` is not consistent throughout your image: if you go by row and wrap around, it goes `0 1 2 0 1 1 2`, so it is not a simple repeating signal.

Comment: Have you considered generating a matrix larger than 5x5 and removing rows or columns in order to end up with 5x5? Think about adding rows or columns (depending on the value of `byrow=`) and see if you find a way to match a repeating `0:2` pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mat <- matrix(0:2, nrow = 7, ncol = 5)

```
> mat
    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0    1    2    0    1
[2,]    1    2    0    1    2
[3,]    2    0    1    2    0
[4,]    0    1    2    0    1
[5,]    1    2    0    1    2
[6,]    2    0    1    2    0
[7,]    0    1    2    0    1
```

mat2 <- mat[-6:-7, ]

```
> mat2
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
 [1,]    0    1    2    0    1
 [2,]    1    2    0    1    2
 [3,]    2    0    1    2    0
 [4,]    0    1    2    0    1
 [5,]    1    2    0    1    2
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was thinking, glad you found it Nikita!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the index numbers of the rows and columns, and combine the value with the modulo operator `%%` like this:

```
n = 5
mat <- matrix(nrow = n, ncol = n)
mat <- (row(mat) + col(mat) + 1) %% 3

> mat
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] 
[1,]    0    1    2    0    1
[2,]    1    2    0    1    2
[3,]    2    0    1    2    0
[4,]    0    1    2    0    1
[5,]    1    2    0    1    2
```